# Stylus - selectors that are near: "+" operator

Tags: css, stylus

Unfortunately I cannot get this working in Stylus:

```
.class1 + .class2
    background: red
```

It doesn't catch this styles for element. Maybe I'm not aware of syntax?

Comment: `+` selector is next-sibling. From [W3C on CSS 2.1 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors): "The selector matches if E1 and E2 share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments)" this means it's not simply "on the same level and occurring somewhere afterwards," but actually "right next to it. There aren't any other elements in between (except possibly text and comments.)"

Comment: show us HTML. so that we can test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS literals:

```
 @css {
   .class1 + .class2
    background: red
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stylus min syntax like that

```
.class-1
    + class-2
```

or if you want use to use '{}'

```
.class-1 {
    + class-2 {
    }
}
```